# How to find rows with similar columns with the exception of a single column

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, window-functions

I'm trying to find rows from the following table

```
T_Date     | Code  | TWS    
2018-01-01 | A0001 | TRDR001
2018-01-01 | A0001 | TRDR002
2018-01-02 | A0002 | TRDR001
2018-01-02 | A0003 | TRDR001
2018-01-03 | A0004 | TRDR001
2018-01-04 | A0004 | TRDR002
2018-01-05 | A0006 | TRDR001
2018-01-05 | A0006 | TRDR003
```

The expecting result is to find those rows which has different TWS on the same date of the same Code

```
T_Date     | Code  | TWS
2018-01-01 | A0001 | TRDR001
2018-01-01 | A0001 | TRDR002
2018-01-05 | A0006 | TRDR001
2018-01-05 | A0006 | TRDR003
```

I have tried some things to no avail.

```
select t.T_Date,t.Code,t.TWS
from trades t 
group by t.T_Date,t.Code,t.TWS
having COUNT(t.TWS)>1
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use the `Exists` operator:

```
Select T_Date, Code, TWS
From table_name T
Where Exists(
  Select 1 From table_name D
  Where D.T_Date = T.T_Date And D.Code = T.Code And D.TWS <> T.TWS)
Order By T_Date, Code, TWS
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/qZefozNK)

Answer (score 0):

Is this code helpful?

```
select distinct T_Date, Code, tws
from trades 
where (T_Date, Code) in 
(    
      select t.T_Date, t.Code 
      from trades t
      group by 
      t.T_Date,t.Code having COUNT(*)>1
)
order by t_date;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bPKzOQKZ)

Comment: You forgot the TWS column, which has to be different and other data should be similar

Comment: I want to fetch those rows which contains same date and code but TWS is different

Comment: But my result is same as what you expect in your question.
https://dbfiddle.uk/jFOTUofU

Comment: I have additional columns in the table that's why your code isn't giving me the result. Can you please restrict the result to only these three columns?

Comment: Bro you should develop your sql skill.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but I got the exact answer from Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a self-join, like this:

```
SELECT T_Date, Code, TWS
FROM trades t1
INNER JOIN trades t2 
ON t1.T_Date = t2.T_Date AND t1.Code = t2.Code
WHERE t1.TWS <> t2.TWS;
```

Answer (score 0):

> The expecting result is to find those rows which has different TWS on the same date of the same Code

I would recommend window functions rather than a subquery or a self-join. That's a single table scan (vs two with other approaches), so it should be more efficient.

We can just compare the min and max values of `tws` over partitions of `t_date, code`; if they do not match, then we retain all rows of the partition:

```
select t.*
from (
    select t.*,
        min(tws) over(partition by t_date, code) min_tws,
        max(tws) over(partition by t_date, code) max_tws
    from mytable t
) t
where min_tws <> max_tws
```